# angular observer changes dont update gui

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-template, subject

I subscribe in names.component to a subject and it triggers when the subject is changed so the observable is working. but why doesn't my GUI react to "lang" change?

this component is in the fields.module.ts and the CacheService is provided by the `app.module.ts`

**names.component.ts**

```html
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import { CacheService } from 'src/app/shared/cache.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'field-names',
      templateUrl: './names.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./names.component.scss']
    })
    export class NamesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
      @Input() value;
      editSub: Subscription;
      editMode;
      langSub: Subscription;
      lang = "de";
    
      constructor(private cache: CacheService) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.langSub = this.cache.subjectLang.subscribe((lang: string) => {
          this.lang = lang; 
        });
    
        this.editSub = this.cache.subjectEdit.subscribe((edit: boolean) => {
          this.editMode = edit; 
        });
      }
    
      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.langSub.unsubscribe();
      }
    }
```

**names.component.html**

```html
<div class="item noBottom" [ngClass]="{
  'has-danger': nameEn.invalid || nameFr.invalid || nameDe.invalid || nameIt.invalid,
  'has-success': nameEn.valid && nameFr.valid && nameDe.valid && nameIt.valid
}">
<div class="d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'display': (lang != 'en' && lang !='*') ? 'none !important' : 'inherit'}">
  <div class="col-md-2 label" i18n="@@tables.general.name">Name {{lang}}</div>
  <div class="col-md-1 flag en"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="e" id="nameEn" placeholder="Name" required [ngModel]="value.l10n.en" name="nameEn" #nameEn="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
    <div *ngIf="nameEn.errors && (nameEn.dirty || nameEn.touched)" class="form-control-feedback" >
      <p *ngIf="nameEn.errors.alphaNum" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.alphaNum">a</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'display': (lang != 'de' && lang !='*') ? 'none !important' : 'inherit'}">
  <div class="col-md-2 label"><span [hidden]="lang == '*'" i18n="@@tables.general.name">Name</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-1 flag de"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="d" id="nameDe" placeholder="Name" required [ngModel]="value.l10n.de" name="nameDe" #nameDe="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
    <div *ngIf="nameDe.errors && (nameDe.dirty || nameDe.touched)" class="form-control-feedback" >
      <p *ngIf="nameDe.errors.alphaNum" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.alphaNum">a</span></p>
      <p *ngIf="nameDe.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.required">r</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'display': (lang != 'fr' && lang !='*') ? 'none !important' : 'block'}">
  <div class="col-md-2 label"><span [hidden]="lang == '*'" i18n="@@tables.general.name">Name</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-1 flag fr"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="f" id="nameFr" placeholder="Nom" required [ngModel]="value.l10n.fr" name="nameFr" #nameFr="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
    <div *ngIf="nameFr.errors && (nameFr.dirty || nameFr.touched)" class="form-control-feedback" >
      <p *ngIf="nameFr.errors.alphaNum" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.alphaNum">a</span></p>
      <p *ngIf="nameFr.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.required">r</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-flex" [ngStyle]="{'display': (lang != 'it' && lang !='*') ? 'none !important' : ''}">
  <div class="col-md-2 label"><span [hidden]="lang == '*'" i18n="@@tables.general.name">Name</span></div>
  <div class="col-md-1 flag it"></div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" accesskey="i" id="nameIt" placeholder="Nome" required [ngModel]="value.l10n.it" name="nameIt" #nameIt="ngModel" [disabled]="!editMode">
    <div *ngIf="nameIt.errors && (nameIt.dirty || nameIt.touched)" class="form-control-feedback" >
      <p *ngIf="nameIt.errors.alphaNum" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.alphaNum">a</span></p>
      <p *ngIf="nameIt.errors.required" class="alert alert-danger"><span i18n="@@tables.general.name">c</span>&nbsp;<span i18n="@@tables.error.required">r</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

what am I doing wrong, I also tried this.cdRef.detectChanges(); to no effect.

Comment: Added brackets to subjectLang and subjectEdit. 

ngOnInit() {
        this.langSub = this.cache.subjectLang().subscribe((lang: string) => {
          this.lang = lang; 
        });
    
        this.editSub = this.cache.subjectEdit().subscribe((edit: boolean) => {
          this.editMode = edit; 
        });
      } 
   
Can you please share code where you are sending info on trigger (.next)

Comment: `subjectLang = new Subject();
  onLangChange(lang: string) {
      this.subjectLang.next(lang);
  }

  subjectEdit = new Subject();
  onEditChange(edit: boolean) {
      this.subjectEdit.next(edit);
  }`

Comment: the brackets are not needed for subjectLang/Edit

Answer (score 0):

i had to move my subscribers from ngOnInit to the constructor